# Matrix to vector minimum comparison without using apply in R

Tags: r, function, vector, vectorization, apply

I am trying to create a function that takes in a matrix `M`  and a vector `v`.  It should then take the elementwise minimum between columns of `M`  and `v`.  As such, the number of rows of `M` = `length(v)`

For example, the below does it for two vectors of equal length.  I want it to work for a matrix compared to a vector.

```
vectorelementwisemin = function(x,y){   #x is a vector, y is a vector (same length)


            ind = which(x > y)
            z = x
            z[ind] <- y[ind]  

            return(z)
}
```

For example, the vectorized function could take in:

```
    M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[2,]    2    2    5    4    2    3    4    1    4     4     4     2
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[5,]    0    6    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0

    v

     0      4      2      1      3      0

And return 

    minmat(M,v)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[2,]    2    2    4    4    2    3    4    1    4     4     4     2
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[5,]    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Can you use `matrix(pmin(as.vector(M), v), ncol=ncol(M))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use `minmat <- function(M, v) pmin(M, v)` although you may want to add something like `if (nrow(M) != length(v)) stop("")`